# Partial Refund in CCAvenue using opencart

Tags: opencart, payment-gateway, ccavenue

Is there any option of refunding partially using CCAvenue with OpenCart?

For Example if a customer orders a product of Rs.1000/- and paid for it. In some
cases admin cancels the product and refunds the product on the following basis - first time he will refund Rs. 500/- second time Rs.300/- and the third time Rs.200/-. Is there any possibility to refund like described above.

Comment: Other than creating a new custom module, i do not believe there is. Opencart only supports returns, not refunds. These are bount to the payment method and require a great deal of extra features.

Comment: @Jonid Bendo, Is there any option in other payment gateway.

Comment: Not what i am aware of, i am afraid that you are bound to create this from scratch, although i have not checked every extension and its features. And also please be aware that security might become a real problem if you want to allow refunds from Opencart, and you should find a payment gateway that allows refunds with commands, hmm saferpay was one that had this option when i created a module for them, i do not know if there are any other options.